# Sympy: Replacement using Wild symbols

Tags: python, regex, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to do generic subexpression replacement.

I want to replace any expression exactly of the form `x*y` to `c`.

Note that `x` and `y` can be any symbol in the expression.

In the code below, I am using Wild to achieve this, but apparently I am unable to have Wild match symbols only, instead of subexpressions - even with using `isinstance=[sp.Symbol]`.

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c = sp.symbols('a b c')

f= a*b - b

x = sp.Wild('x', isinstance=[sp.Symbol])
y = sp.Wild('y', isinstance=[sp.Symbol])

expr = f.replace(x*y, c)
```

This leads to the following result,

```
print expr
c
```

The expected answer though is: `c - b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isinstance` isn't a real argument for `Wild`.

The argument you're looking for is `properties`. Although it doesn't seem to be documented, the argument takes a list of functions which should hold true for matched expressions. You can use this to match symbols with

```
In [7]: f= a*b - b

In [14]: y = sp.Wild('y', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Symbol)])

In [15]: x = sp.Wild('x', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Symbol)])

In [16]: f.replace(x*y, c)
Out[16]: -b + c
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
syms = sorted(set(a for a in f.atoms() if type(a) == sp.Symbol), key=str)
f.subs((s1*s2, c) for s1, s2 in it.combinations(syms, 2))
```

Seems to work okay in this example:

```
import itertools as it

a, b, c, d = sp.symbols('a b c d')
f = 3*a**2*b*c**b+b*c**2+25+(a+b+c*a/4)/(a*c+3**(b*c))-8

syms = sorted(set(a for a in f.atoms() if type(a) == sp.Symbol), key=str)
repls = [(s1*s2, d) for s1,s2 in it.combinations(syms, 2)]
print('variables:     ' + str(syms))
print('replacements:  ' + str(repls))

expr = f.subs(repls)
print('Before:  ' + str(f))
print('After:   ' + str(expr))
```

Comment: Maybe it must be `f.subs(..., simultaneous=True)` in some cases, or for better performance.